# Calculating $R^2$ two different ways

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I am calculating my $R^2$ for a model two different ways. I used `pred = predict(model, newdata = mydata, se.fit = T)` and then calculated `1 - (mean(pred$se.fit))/var(mydata)` and this gave me a value of `0.9903`.

However, then I calculated `rmse.model = sqrt(mean((mydata - pred$fit)^2))` and then found `1 - rmse.model^2/var(mydata)` and this gave me a value of `0.0372`....so I'm not sure what is happening. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the source of your first formula?  Why do you think it ought to yield the $R^2$?  When you plot the data, which $R^2$ result appears to be consistent with that plot?

Comment: This may be a naive question, but why are you manually computing R2?  I would personally like to know.

Comment: @ChrisC Preferably, you should always know how a statistical method you use works in principle and for this relatively simple stuff you should be able to do the calculations manually.

Comment: Thanks @Roland.  I was just wondering if there would be any advantage to manually computing the R2 in an analysis versus using the automatically generated one. Is there any additional information gained? Sorry if this is off topic!

Comment: @Chris In addition to Roland's answer, which is a good one, making calculations like this are useful to make sure you understand exactly what the software output means.

Answer (score 0):

The second calculation divides the standard deviation of the residuals by the overall variance, when the calculation should be the quotient of variances.

I do not know the `se.fit` syntax to say if the first calculation is correct. However, you would want to calculate the variance of the residuals to use in the numerator, not the standard deviation of the residuals like your code does.